# jQuery deferrend; callback for waiting functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I have to call 3 functions with AJAX requests before one of the functions can be finished. All functions needs the same data, so I want to start the AJAX request only once. I think that I need a functionality to call 2 of the 3 functions to wait and provide the data at the end. Maybe the problem is that I am new to jQuery Deferred and dont find some basic stuff? Thanks for help!

Because my script is to complex as example so I created this demo: (I hope it is self explanatory)

```
<script>
    var requestRunning = false;

    //do some ajax request etc...
    function doSomething() {
        return {
            doIt: function (test, startDelay) {
                var dfd = $.Deferred();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (requestRunning == false) {
                        console.log("starting ajax call:", test);

                        requestRunning = true;

                        //Fake ajax call
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            dfd.resolve(test);
                            // Todo: A done; provide data to waiting B and C.
                        }, 500);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("ajax call allready running, waiting...", test);
                    }
                }, startDelay);

                return dfd.promise();
            }
        }
    }

    // Fake delay for function calls in really short time
    var master = doSomething();
    var a = master.doIt("a", 10);
    var b = master.doIt("b", 15);
    var c = master.doIt("c", 12);

    // Do some stuff with the received data...
    a.done(function myfunction(result) {
        console.log(result + " done");
    });

    b.done(function myfunction(result) {
        console.log(result + " done");
    });

    c.done(function myfunction(result) {
        console.log(result + " done");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It would appear that you want to sequence a,b and c but it's not 100% clear what the sequence should be. For example you could have `a then b then c` or `a then (b and c in parallel)` or `(a and b in parallel) then c`, or `(a, b and c in parallel) then something_else`. Any of these is possible.

Comment: There is none defined order for the A, B and C. Sometimes only A needs the data; othertimes all 3 need the data. But if more then one functions need the data, I want only to start 1 ajax call (the result data for A / B / C is the same)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if what you want to do is to start three ajax calls at once and then know when all of them are done, since jQuery ajax calls already return a promise, you can use that promise and `$.when()` like this:

```
var p1 = $.ajax(...);
var p2 = $.ajax(...);
var p3 = $.ajax(...);

$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
    // results of the three ajax calls in r1[0], r2[0] and r3[0]
});
```

---

Or, you can even do it without the intermediate variables:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(...),
    $.ajax(...),
    $.ajax(...)
).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
    // results of the three ajax calls in r1[0], r2[0] and r3[0]
});
```

---

If you are calling functions that themselves do ajax calls, then you can just return the ajax promise from those functions and use the function call with the structure above:

```
function doSomethingAjax() {
    // some code
    return $.ajax(...).then(...);
}

$.when(
    doSomethingAjax1(...),
    doSomethingAjax2(...),
    doSomethingAjax3(...)
).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
    // results of the three ajax calls in r1[0], r2[0] and r3[0]
});
```

Comment: Yep I know the way to wait if more then more AJAX calls done. But I need only 1 AJAX call and the result for more than one functions. The problem is: I cant start the AJAX call and after success starting the functions. The functions has to start the AJAX call, if the call is ongoing and a other function tries to start the call again, the other function has to wait for the result of the running AJAX call.

So I need an observer or something like that?

Comment: @Chris - javascript doesn't ever "wait" for async operations to be done.  It just doesn't work that way.  So, you can't ever make your function wait until the ajax call finishes.  Instead, you will have to give your function an async interface with a callback and that callback can be called when the function is done.